# p:selectCheckboxMenu ajax event name for on close

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I need to trigger action on the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` when user finishes his selection(s) (on close). the `datatable` need to be updated with new selected columns(done).

I couldn't find the event name of the ajax behavior that suits this principal role of a Menu.the default ajax behavior of the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` updates the datatable on every selection which is annoying for me and the user, i need only the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` to trigger action when it is closed.

Here is my code :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="colser"
                      scrollHeight="100"
                      filterMatchMode="contains"
                      filter="true"
                      label="Colonnes"
                      value="#{datatableBean.selectedstateOptions}">  
   <f:selectItems value="#{datatableBean.columner}"
                  var="list"
                  itemLabel="#{list.listname}" 
                  itemValue="#{list.headername}"/>  
   <p:ajax  event="close_event_name_here"
            update=":form1:tabexam"
            listener="#{datatableBean.updateCols()}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try onhide attribute of the p:selectCheckboxMenu.

```
      <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="colser"
                  scrollHeight="100"
                  filterMatchMode="contains"
                  filter="true"
                  label="Colonnes"
                  value="#{datatableBean.selectedstateOptions}"
                  onHide="executeOnOnhide();>  
            <f:selectItems value="#{datatableBean.columner}"
              var="list"
              itemLabel="#{list.listname}" 
              itemValue="#{list.headername}"/>  
      </p:selectCheckboxMenu>  

      <p:remoteCommand  name="executeOnOnhide"
        update=":form1:tabexam" process="@this form:colser"
        action="#{datatableBean.updateCols()}"/>
```

The link for the documentation guide for primefaces for your reference
http://primefaces.org/documentation.html

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried it, and it's not working, the table is never updated, and updateCols() never invoked.

Comment: add @this also along with selectCheckBoxMenu id in process attribiute of remote command and give a try. Parenthesis are not required in action if you are not sending any params.

Comment: The <p:remoteCommand> tag can be into <p:selectCheckboxMenu> as well in case you only want it only inside that selectCheckboxMenu scope